# Function returning a result but gives an error that it doesnt

Tags: java

I try to make a function that checks if  a number is prime or not and eclips gives me the error that i have to return a result even thought i do.

```
public static boolean isPrime (int x){
    for(int i=2;i<x;i++){
        if(x%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if x%i != 0?  It returns nothing, and the compiler expects it to return a Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is incomplete:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int x){
    for(int i=2;i<x;i++){
        if(x%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return true if it is prime :

```
public static boolean isPrime (int x){
    for(int i=2;i<x;i++){
        if(x%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```